# Replication between SQL Server 2005 and Azure database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication

Is it possible to set up transitional replication between a SQL Server 2005 and a SQL Azure database?

My server is nearing end of life and I would rather migrate to a cloud infrastructure instead of buying new hardware.

I’ve been unable to find any documentation stating whether or not SQL Azure Data Sync can co-exist with SQL Server Replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the core of your question ("Can you set up replication between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Azure Database?"), but my assumption is a resounding "NO".

There are tools to migrate from SQL Server to Azure though - it's been discussed on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940491/migrate-sql-server-database-to-sql-azure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471871/transfer-sql-server-data-to-sql-azure).
The consensus seems to be that [This SQL Azure Migration Wizard (CodePlex hosted project)](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com) is the way to go. It doesn't appear to be a live-sync migration though, so you will probably need to take an outage window unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Today there are two recommended methods for SQL Server:

- Migration with downtime (SQL Server >=2005)
- Transactional Replication (SQL Server >=2012 and Azure SQL DB >= V12)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate